# breakpoints in Iphone 6+

Tags: css

I am having some problems with my responsive grid. It is problaly something to do with my breakpoints. To see if the breakpoints is working in the Blisk browser, I started with just setting a color on the font, so I would see what is changing.

The reason why I set the first one to 414 px, is that it works on all mobiles except Iphone 6+ and Nexus 6. But those breakpoints are not working. The head-text does not change color.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 414px) {

    .header-box {
    background-color: #163A4E;
    height: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    .header-text h1 {
        color:red;
    }

    .header-text h2 {
        color:green;
    }
}

/* Iphone 6 + and Nexus 6*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 415px) and (max-device-width : 736px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
      .header-text h1 {
        color:yellow;
    }

    .header-text h2 {
        color:pink;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try testing it on chrome? the devtools are great + blisk is still in beta it's not stable yet

Comment: Ah ok. I did not know I could test it in chrome with the responsive design. The only thing I do is to drag the side back and fourth, but it is pretty time consuming to do that all the time. Is there a responsive design section in developer tools?

Comment: of course there is, on the top left you see an icon of a phone with tablet click it to start using different devices, it's so good that they even mimic the behavior of the device like the headers the device returns for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you have `max-device-width` but it should be `max-width` since 
[`device-width` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-width)

Also, don't use the `orientation` since [it is not working](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation) (yet).

Your CSS would look like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 414px) {

    .header-box {
    background-color: #163A4E;
    height: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    .header-text h1 {
        color:red;
    }

    .header-text h2 {
        color:green;
    }
}

/* Iphone 6 + and Nexus 6*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 415px) and (max-width : 736px) { 
      .header-text h1 {
        color:yellow;
    }

    .header-text h2 {
        color:pink;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know Blisk, but I always use FireFox and its developer tool. CRTL + SHIFT + M to get the responsive view. Also you could try some javascript to detect the resolution using `alert( "W" + window.screen.availWidth + " H" + window.screen.availHeight )`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Is there a good site, browser etc where I could test it, instead of using Blisk?